Right click on image in Microsoft Edge brings QR code popup
Recently, I have been having problems with images in Microsoft Edge Version 127.0.2651.98 (Official build) (64-bit). When I right-click on the photograph, I would expect a popup window where I can choose from options. These popups rarely; more often, I receive popups with a QR code, sometimes photographer editor or blinking. How to debug? I am on Linux, and Microsoft doesn't provide support for Linux users. On Firefox, this works just fine.
I thought it might be malware because it started to happen after installing certain add-ons. So, I reinstalled Edge, and it didn't help. Then I uninstalled Edge, removed most of its remaining files in user /.config/ and /.cache/, including in some other system dirs, and installed it again, but it didn't help.
Looking at "Right Click to Image Causes refresh on explorer," I wonder whether Edge causes this problem or whether it might be caused by system such as key bindings.
